# How to get average from a column

Tags: mysql, database

I'm newbie with databases, and in school professor gave us homework to do.

I have the following tables:

**games**

```
id | game_id | game_name
```

**categories**

```
id | cat_name
```

**helper**

```
id | game_id | cat_id
```

**prices**

```
id | game_id | price | developer
```

I need to select average price for category with an id 2 and display result to loos like:

```
cat_name | avg_price
```

So this is my logic:

1. First i need to find what games are assigned to category with id=2
2. Then i need to select only games from table prices which are equal
   to result from the step 1
3. Then i need somehow to write result as
   requested

So far this is my code:

```
select prices.price
from (select helper.game_id
from helper
where helper.cat_id="2")
where prices.game_id = helper.game_id
```

When I run it, in phpMyAdmin i receive error: Every derived table must have its own alias.

So how to assign that aliases (I already tried to look over internet, but im not sure if i understand them)?

Even better would if somebody give me ready code from which i can learn something.

Thanks!

Comment: The error is due to a lack of alias on the subquery `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT...FROM...WHERE) AS alias_for_subq WHERE....`  but that doesn't look to be the solution to your query requirement.

Comment: I hope your professor didn't come up with the table schema for this; it could be designed better and more correctly.  developer should be a column on the game table and consistent id column naming would be better.  It also looks like your original query would also fail because `prices` is not in any `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because when you do a subselect like you have, you need to give that "derived" table that results from the subselect an alias like this:

```
select prices.price
from (select helper.game_id
from helper
where helper.cat_id="2") as helper_sub
where prices.game_id = helper_sub.game_id
```

Note the use of the alias in the WHERE clause as well since you are using that as the condition.

Now that I have answered the initial question, let me show you a better way to do this.  You should be using a JOIN here, as subselects are typically not very optimal.

```
SELECT c.cat_name AS cat_name, AVG(p.price) as avg_price
FROM
categories AS c
INNER JOIN helper AS h ON c.id = h.cat_id
INNER JOIN prices AS p ON h.game_id = p.game_id
WHERE c.id = 2
GROUP BY c.id
```

Of course my assumption here is that there are indexes on all the "id" fields both where they are primary keys and foreign keys (like in the helper and prices tables).  that is also why c.id is used for grouping rather than c.cat_name, as in a typical relational database you might not have an index on a field such as `cat_name` that is not being used for joins, to perform WHERE filtering, or for sorting purposes.

Comment: I was going to post basically the same answer with a couple differences.  First, the average needs to be selected `AS avg_price` and second, the `GROUP BY` is redundant since you're only selecting one category.

Comment: Now im receiving "Unknown column 'prices.price' in 'field list'". I dont know hows that, because when i run select prices.price from prices then i got list of the prices.

Comment: @DimmestDanger At the end of my comment on the question, I addressed this.  It's because you have not added `prices` to the query in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: @G-Nugget Yes, I forgot to add the alias for the aggregated field, I have edited my answer to reflect this. While in this specific instance the GROUP BY could be omitted with the same results, I wanted to specifically show it here as it would be needed if you wanted to either eliminate the category filter, or provide multiple categories to filter on.  With this being an instructional answer I thought it fitting.

Comment: @DimmestDanger I didn't really spend any time evaluating your initial query, you would actually need another subselect to achieve what you wanted to do with your original approach. I was simply trying to answer the question about the alias.  Please note that joining the tables is the proper way to query this data in a straightforward example like what you have been given where the tables are clearly related.

Answer (score 0):

```
select prices.price
from (select helper.game_id
    from helper
    where helper.cat_id="2") AS subtable
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^---alias for derived table
where prices.game_id = subtable.game_id
                       ^^^^^^^^---using the alias
```

Comment: I tried this too and im receiving "Unknown column 'prices.price' in 'field list'". I dont know hows that, because when i run select prices.price from prices then i got list of the prices.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87f52/2)**

```
SELECT
c.cat_name,
AVG(price ) AS avg_price
FROM categories c
  LEFT JOIN helper h
    ON c.id = h.cat_id
  LEFT JOIN games g
    ON g.id = h.game_id
  LEFT JOIN prices p 
    ON p.game_id = g.id
WHERE c.id= 2
GROUP BY c.cat_name
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO helper
    (`id`, `game_id`, `cat_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (3, 3, 1),  
    (2, 2, 2)
    INSERT INTO prices
        (`id`, `game_id`, `price`, `developer`)
    VALUES
        (1, 1, '12.5', 'EA'),
        (2, 2, '15.6', 'Woozie'),
        (3, 3, '25.6', 'Woozie')
```

Result:

```
| CAT_NAME | AVG_PRICE |
------------------------
|     good |     14.05 |
```